# Split Varchar with information into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a issue where I have a long varchar with different type of information in it. I am trying to split it up into a table so I can work on it. The item type information is split by 4 spaces. The system is built already like that so I need to find a way to deal with these kind of varchars.

```
DECLARE @V AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Price Updated. Previous Value: 20.20 New Value: 30.20 by UsernameA    Item Name Updated. Previous Value: XBOX New Value: XBOX2 by UsernameB    Item Colour Updated. Previous Value: Black New Value: Silver by UsernameC'
```

I have created the following temp table which will hold the data:

```
DECLARE @info AS TABLE
(
    Name VARCHAR(500),
    Previous_Value NUMERIC(8, 2) ,
    New_Value NUMERIC(8, 2) ,
    User_By VARCHAR(500)
)
```

I am trying to split the content into the table like below:

```
-- Name                 Previous_Value      New_Value   User_By
-- Price Updated.       20.20               30.20       UsernameA
-- Item Name Updated.   XBOX                XBOX2       UsernameB
-- Item Colour Updated. Black               Silver      UsernameC
```

Can anyone help me how to do this? Looking for an performance approach as I be dealing with lots of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server is not very good at string manipulation.  But if you have to do the operations in the database, it is possible:

```
select s.value,
       left(s.value, charindex(' Previous Value:', s.value)) as name,
       left(v.prev, charindex(' New Value:', v.prev)) as prev_value,
       left(v.new_val, charindex(' by ', v.new_val)) as new_value,
       stuff(v.new_val, 1, charindex(' by ', v.new_val) + 3, '') as user_by
from string_split(replace(@v, '    ', '|'), '|') s cross apply
     (values (substring(s.value, charindex(' Previous Value:', s.value) + 17, 1000),
              substring(s.value, charindex(' New Value:', s.value) + 12, 1000)
             )
     ) v(prev, new_val);
```

I would recommend using a more appropriate tool such as Python to convert the data into a delimited file and then just load that into the database.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be77ffd8125fd08389d7d200ae92b4e9) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Good solution. Took a while to figure it out. I never used string_split function and cross apply before.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure Gordon's is a more performant (+1), but here is another option using  a bit of `JSON`

**Example**

```
DECLARE @V AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Price Updated. Previous Value: 20.20 New Value: 30.20 by UsernameA    Item Name Updated. Previous Value: XBOX New Value: XBOX2 by UsernameB    Item Colour Updated. Previous Value: Black New Value: Silver by UsernameC'

Select * 
 From  OpenJson(
                '[{"Name":"'+
                replace(
                replace(
                replace(
                replace(@V,'   ','"},{"Name":"')
                ,' by ','","by":"')
                ,'New Value:','","New_Value":"')
                ,'Previous Value:','","Previous_Value":"')
                +'"}]'
              )
With (
      [Name]       varchar(100) '$.Name',
      [Prev_Value] varchar(100) '$.Previous_Value',
      [New_Value]  varchar(100) '$.New_Value',
      [User_By]    varchar(100) '$.by'
    )
```

**Results**

```
Name                     Prev_Value     New_Value   User_By
Price Updated.           20.20          30.20       UsernameA
Item Name Updated.       XBOX           XBOX2       UsernameB
Item Colour Updated.     Black          Silver      UsernameC
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JSON idea by @John Cappelletti, similar implementation using XML

```sql
DECLARE @V AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Price Updated. Previous Value: 20.20 New Value: 30.20 by UsernameA    Item Name Updated. Previous Value: XBOX New Value: XBOX2 by UsernameB    Item Colour Updated. Previous Value: Black New Value: Silver by UsernameC'
DECLARE @V_XML xml =  
                '<root><Name value="'+
                replace(
                replace(
                replace(
                replace(@V,'   ','"/><Name value="')
                ,' by ','" by="')
                ,'New Value:','" New_Value="')
                ,'Previous Value:','" Previous_Value="')
                +'"/></root>'

select c.value('(./@value)[1]','varchar(50)') as Name,
c.value('(./@Previous_Value)[1]','varchar(50)') as Prev_Value,
c.value('(./@New_Value)[1]','varchar(50)') as New_Value,
c.value('(./@by)[1]','varchar(50)') as by_Person
FROM @V_XML.nodes('root/Name') AS t(c)
```

| Name | Prev_Value | New_Value | by_Person |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Price Updated. | 20.20 | 30.20 | UsernameA |
| Item Name Updated. | XBOX | XBOX2 | UsernameB |
| Item Colour Updated. | Black | Silver | UsernameC |